# Custom ContentControl does not display content after templating?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, templates, xaml

I've created new custom control called `DataGridInsertRowPresenter` that inherits from `ContentControl`. Everything worked well.

Then I added new style that changes template for it and it does not display content any more. Here is the control:

```
public class DataGridInsertRowPresenter : ContentControl {
    static DataGridInsertRowPresenter() {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(DataGridInsertRowPresenter), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(DataGridInsertRowPresenter)));
    }
}
```

Here is my template:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Primitives:DataGridInsertRowPresenter}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ContentControl}}" >
    <Setter Property="Template" >
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

What is wrong with my code ?

Comment: Did you get a solution for this? Any of the suggested answers it, in that case, can you mark it as answered?

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your assemblyinfo.cs is missing an attribute to tell it where to look for resources. Check that you have the following code in your assemblyinfo.cs:

```
[assembly: ThemeInfo(
ResourceDictionaryLocation.None, //where theme specific resource dictionaries are located
//(used if a resource is not found in the page, 
// or application resource dictionaries)
ResourceDictionaryLocation.SourceAssembly //where the generic resource dictionary is located
//(used if a resource is not found in the page, 
// app, or any theme specific resource dictionaries)
```

)]

And make sure your style is in Themes\Generic.xaml (or referenced as a merged dictionary)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `TargetType` to your `ControlTemplate` since `Control` does not have a property called `Content`:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Primitives:DataGridInsertRowPresenter}">
```